# Thunderbird 115.3.1 (Supernova) attachment display problem after allowing remote content in a message

Tags: email, thunderbird, 23.04, attachment

The new version of Thunderbird (as upgraded today) has a bug, where for *some* (?) emails I am unable to select an attachment for view.

In the preview pane or in the separate message window (displayed when I double-click on the message) I scroll down to see the list of attachments at the bottom, but nothing is displayed except the main message's contents, as if the message has no attachment(s). So, I am unable to select and view an attachment.

This happens for new or old archived messages. However, some messages do not have this problem and it looks like the displaying or not displaying the attachment section after the end of the message content is dependent on the first section (HTML content) of the message, because this problem occurs after allowing to **Show remote content for this message** in **Preferences**.

*Note*: Selecting **View » Message Body As » Simple HTML** corrects the problem and attachment list is displayed at the bottom as it should be. **View » Message Body As » Original HTML** (*and allowing remote content to be displayed*) hides the attachments again. This is obviously a bug. Has anybody else met with this problem?

Normally, I would not want to revert to a previous version of Thunderbird; so I am asking if there is a workaround for viewing the attachment of an email in the 115.3.1 version of Thunderbird?

---

**Update:** I filed a bug report and more details are given there. You can follow it from https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1856929